# I am not quite understanding the output of the following function

Tags: c, function, ascii

I wrote a simple sum() function in C with two arguments of integer type. But, while calling the function in main, I passed char type variables. The problem is I am not able to understand the output of the program. Following is the code.:

```
void sum(int x,int y)
{
    printf(" x=%d  y=%d\n",x,y);
    printf("%d",x+y);
}

void main()
{
    char a,b,add;
    printf("Enter two values: ");
    scanf("%c%c",&a,&b);
    sum(a,b);           //calling
}
```

If I input a=A and b=A then it should give me the addition of ASCII values of A, i.e. 130, but it is giving me 97.
When I try to print the value of x and y, it prints x=65 y=32. I don't understand why it stores 32 in y? Can someone please explain this.

Comment: If `y` is 32, you typed a space between the two letters `A` in your input.  Don't!  The `%c` conversion specification does not skip white space.  Either use `" %c %c"` as the input format (skipping optional white space before each non-space entered), or type `AA` instead of `A A`.

Comment: Because you have separated the two A's with a space (of value 32 :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your input was `A A`, which is `A<spacebar>A`. The `scanf("%c%c",&a,&b)` read exactly two characters, `A` and `<spacebar>`, which resulted x = 65(`A`), y= 32(`<spacebar>`). If you want to get the intended output, your input should be `AA`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are giving input as `A A` instead of `AA`. For the former, x stores `65` and y stores `32` as the ASCII value of space is `32`.

Comment: Yes, i just checked that what you mentioned. its running fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store 124abc in a integer variable then it will store only 124.
And in the definition of character constant/variable it can save all ASCII 255 character's which include also space(spacebar),tab(tab key),newline(enter key).
so when you run code and the screen show "Enter two values: ". You type 'A' which store in variable 'a'. Now you press space bar which is also a character constant which have value of ASCII 32 store into variable 'b'. so avoid this situation you should put a space before %c so it never read enter key or space bar.
Or use fflush(stdin) function.